# How can I properly handle touch events of a UIButton on top of another UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to recreate the function of the clear button in UITextFields but with a UIButton and as such have a UIButton as a subview of another UIButton. I read somewhere that I need to have the superview handle the touch events of the subview.

The post that hinted at that was outdated and in obj-C so I'm looking for modern and swift version.

Answer (score 0):

Placing a button on another button is a kind of bad implementation in spite of any requirements. 
Hope you find out a right way to solve this problem.

Or you can just use a combination of enabling or disabling buttons according to the situation.